# Can't alter table field from float to decimal in mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, database, decimal, mysql-workbench, alter

I have created a table with a `FLOAT` type column. However, I found that when I query the column's `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG` values I get inaccurate numbers, where the returned value is larger than what is actually stored in the table. For example, this is the actual maximum number in the table: 0.00348675. Somehow, `MAX` returns this: 0.0034867459908127785

The inaccuracy turned to be due to choosing `FLOAT` as type. For this reason, I want to change the columns type to `DECIMAL.`

I use `mysql-workbench` in Ubuntu 18. When I right-click the table and choose `Alter Table` I can change the data types. Unfortunately, when I change the concerned field from `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT` returns again automatically. The workbench can not choose `DECIMAL` for some reason. See this picture. I can choose DECIMAL from a list. Then when I move the mouse elsewhere to click on the next empty row, so I can click `Apply`, the `DECIMAL` disappear and `FLOAT` returns again:

[image]
Can anyone advise me what is the reason for the prolem? how to overcome the issue?

Comment: How big would you like your decimal to be and how many decimal characters?

Comment: The column values are results of this python 3.6.5 function called: `time.process_time()` which so far I do not see how long it is in the specs.

Comment: I just found that, the value in the original file is: `0.003486746000000096`. When I loaded it into a table with `FLOAT()` type, it became: `0.00348675`. then when I query MAX, it is returned as: `0.0034867459908127785`. This is really confusing. I want the numbers to be stored exactly as I load them from the file. I need them intact in all stages of loading to querying the `MAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are encoded in binary, not decimal.  Hence, most fractional numbers cannot be represented exactly when stored.  (Numbers ending with .5, .25, .75, .125, etc) can be stored exactly because they involve powers of 2.

`FLOAT` is good to *about* 7 significant digits; `DOUBLE` to about 16.

```
0.00348675              You stored this decimal
0.003486746000000096    After conversion to binary, then back to decimal
0.0034867459908127785   See below
```

(I suspect you actually stored `0.003486756`.)

Certain calculations are done in `DOUBLE`; I suspect `MAX()` does such.  That involved converting the `FLOAT` to `DOUBLE`.  Nothing is lost *in this conversion*.

OK, I am at a loss to finish the explanation.

Suffice it to say -- Whenever using `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, be aware that arithmetic and displaying have quirks like this.

There are cases where MySQL tries to avoid such problems by using `DECIMAL`.  I would *guess* that that somehow is involved here because the middle number above has about 14 *significant digits*, not 16, implying that something other than `DOUBLE` is involved -- perhaps `DECIMAL(..., 16)`.  Note: that is *decimal places*, as distinct from *significant* digits_.

If you would like to pursue this further, provide a short test case in a bug filed at http://bugs.mysql.com and post the like to it here.